# Uploading a large file in multipart using OkHttp

Tags: android, file-upload, upload, okhttp

What are my options for uploading a single large file (more specifically, to s3) in multipart in Android using OKhttp?

Comment: can you please update with the used code to solve this issue?

Comment: You can follow this one also http://stackoverflow.com/a/34037063/1318946

Comment: None of these solutions handle a 'large' file. Please delete them all so that a real solution can be documented.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [OkHttp Recipes page](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes), this code uploads an image to Imgur:

```
private static final String IMGUR_CLIENT_ID = "...";
private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");

private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void run() throws Exception {
  // Use the imgur image upload API as documented at https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image
  RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
      .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
      .addPart(
          Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"title\""),
          RequestBody.create(null, "Square Logo"))
      .addPart(
          Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\""),
          RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File("website/static/logo-square.png")))
      .build();

  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .header("Authorization", "Client-ID " + IMGUR_CLIENT_ID)
      .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/image")
      .post(requestBody)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

  System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
```

You'll need to adapt this to S3, but the classes you need should be the same.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Is there any way to track progress of the request assuming I know the content length?

Comment: @TomerWeller you can create a custom RequestBody that tracks bytes moved. You'll want to wrap the Sink passed to the RequestBody.

Comment: Tomer, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962595/tracking-progress-of-multipart-file-upload-using-okhttp/26376724#26376724

Comment: If I have the image in byte[] I tried doing this: `addPart(Headers.of("..."), RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, imageBytes))`; But this doesn't work. It puts the byte data in the headers instead of the body. Any idea why?

Comment: I figured it out. With imgur, you don't have to provide a filename, so sending the image bytes like I did in the above comment worked. However, for the API I'm actually talking to, it expects a filename so this worked: `multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart("image", fileName, entry.getValue());`

Comment: That is great, but you can also add the attributes to POST more easily using: .addFormDataPart("file", "profile.png", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile)) and .addFormDataPart("id", "1") for string attribute

Comment: MultiPartBuilder is called MultipartBody.Builder now, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676044/multipartbuilder-cant-be-resolved-in-okhttp3-0-0-rc1

Comment: Hi buddies,
for uploading image is it good to use asynchronous or not?
you know, I don't understand what is the difference between asynchronous and synchronous....

Comment: Hi guys,  please answer this question I am struck here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520520/how-to-add-list-of-object-i-e-userdata-type-to-multipartbody-in-okhttpclient

Comment: The link is broken to recipe page. Here is the link: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostMultipart.java

Comment: This fails to load a large file and causes an OOM exception

Comment: To deal with large files and `RequestBody` use the Okio library. I provided an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68481022/2807177

Answer (score 43):

Get OkHttp 2.1, and use `MultipartBuilder.addFormDataPart()` which takes the filename as a parameter.

```
       /**
         * Upload Image
         *
         * @param memberId
         * @param sourceImageFile
         * @return
         */
        public static JSONObject uploadImage(String memberId, String sourceImageFile) {
    
            try {
                File sourceFile = new File(sourceImageFile);
    
                Log.d(TAG, "File...::::" + sourceFile + " : " + sourceFile.exists());
             //Determining the media type        
             final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = sourceImageFile.endsWith("png") ? 

                MediaType.parse("image/png") : MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
                
    
                RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                        .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("member_id", memberId)
                        .addFormDataPart("file", "profile.png", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, sourceFile))
                        .build();
    
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(URL_UPLOAD_IMAGE)
                        .post(requestBody)
                        .build();
    
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return new JSONObject(response.body().string());
    
            } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Other Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

#Edited for okhttp3:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

**RequestBody** replaced by:

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file", filename, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile))
                    .addFormDataPart("result", "my_image")
                    .build();
```

#Uploaded Demo on [GITHUB](https://github.com/pratikbutani/OKHTTPUploadImage):
##I have added my answer for [Multiple Image Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34411666/1318946) :)

Comment: @Pratik Butani It works but i want to read response from API. I have to do another task based on response.

Comment: @droid_dev its returning `JSONObject` return value. check it.

Comment: I am using enqueue method instead of execute. Can we send multiple images through multipart??

Comment: I got answer on my question

Comment: I got the answer too regarding multiple images. Still i don't see the response from API instead it throws okHttpResponse.

Comment: MultipartBuilder can not resolved please update your code.

Comment: @ArpitPatel Edited :) :)

Comment: @PratikButani What is .addFormDataPart("result", "my_image") ?!

Comment: For pdf what to do

Comment: @priyankasinghal Change `MediaType.parse("application/pdf")`

Comment: Thanks Pratik. I did it yesterday.Thanks a lot :-). It worked

Comment: Is Multipart the one that makes uploading a large file possible? I am using RequestBody and seems like I am unable to upload a very large file.

Comment: To deal with large files use the Okio library. I provided an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68481022/2807177

Answer (score 7):

For okhttp 4.* use the `MultipartBody.Builder`:

```
fun postMultipart(url: String, text: String, imagePath: String, imageFileName: String): okhttp3.Response? {
    val file = File(imagePath)
    val fileRequestBody = file.asRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaType())
    val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
        .addFormDataPart("text", text)
        .addFormDataPart("image", imageFileName, fileRequestBody)
        .build()

    val request = getRequestBuilder(url)
        .post(requestBody)
        .build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
        return response
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Multipart` the one that makes uploading a large file possible? I am using `RequestBody` and seems like I am unable to upload a very large file.

Comment: To deal with large files use the Okio library. I provided an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68481022/2807177

Answer (score 2):

for   okhttp 2.6.0                                                                                                              {

```
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/xxx/share/" + "ic_launcher.png");
        String contentType = file.toURL().openConnection().getContentType();
        RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), file);

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("fileUploadType","1")
                .addFormDataPart("miniType",contentType)
                .addFormDataPart("ext",file.getAbsolutePath().substring(file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".")))
                .addFormDataPart("fileTypeName","img")
                .addFormDataPart("Filedata","ss.png",fileBody)
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(Contains.MULTIPARTY_POST)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvGetNews.setText("upload fail");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvGetNews.setText("upload success");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `Multipart` the one that makes uploading a large file possible? I am using `RequestBody` and seems like I am unable to upload a very large file.

Comment: To deal with large files and `RequestBody` use the Okio library. I provided an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68481022/2807177

Answer (score 1):

In Android you usally part from an `Uri`. The problem when using large files is that you easily run into `OutOfMemoryError` if you try to read the full stream to a byte array (everything in memory) or you end up creating useless files with Uri stream. This is because `RequestBody` doesn't support creation from `Stream` (because sometimes OkHttp needs to read it many times, if you get a 30X redirect for instance) or `Uri` (because OkHttp is not an Android library).

But OkHttp provides the library Okio, with convenient classes emulating Streams (`Source` and `Sink`) and more convenient internal usage.

So, to create a `BodyRequest` form an `Uri` avoiding any `OutOfMemoryError` due to large files create it this way:

```java
private static final MediaType MULTIPART_FOR_DATA = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");

private @NotNull RequestBody getFilePart(Uri largeFileUri) {

        return new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return MULTIPART_FOR_DATA;
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(@NotNull BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                try (Source source = Okio.source(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mediaUri))) {
                    sink.writeAll(source);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Thank you to everyone posting and commenting in the folowing GitHub thread https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585