# How to show download percent while loading images in Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

How can I add a progress bar showing download progress in **percent**? My image files are on remote server and big enough to take about 30 seconds. I need to inform user about percent of download.

Comment: See the implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962595/tracking-progress-of-multipart-file-upload-using-okhttp

Comment: @Nikola: This is not answer. He is asking progress bar with percentage in Picasso.

Comment: He is not asking for progress bar integration, that is very easy and lots of tutorials available... But the problem here is. In Picasso how to show. Since Picasso is library to download and cache images.