# Retrofit - OkHttp 3 - Multipart upload progress

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit, okhttp, retrofit2

Is it possible to get a *real* progress of uploading file using Retrofit 2 and OkHttp 3?

I'm testing this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36260692/1885562
but it's not working as you may expect. I'm getting 100% progress after couple dozens of milliseconds, but the upload should take over 10 seconds (3MB file on 1Mbit connection). I'm guessing that there's some sort of buffer before actual HTTP call.

How to solve this?