# OkHttp upload progress is not in sync with the actual upload

Tags: android, file-upload, okhttp

I'm trying to track the progress of an upload using OkHttp. I have created a custom `RequestBody` with the following body (courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528751/okhttp-3-tracking-multipart-upload-progress/36260692#36260692)) which writes to sink and publishes the progress.

```
public class CountingFileRequestBody extends RequestBody {
    private static final String TAG = "CountingFileRequestBody";

    private final ProgressListener listener;
    private final String key;
    private final MultipartBody multipartBody;
    protected CountingSink mCountingSink;

    public CountingFileRequestBody(MultipartBody multipartBody,
                                   String key,
                                   ProgressListener listener) {
        this.multipartBody = multipartBody;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public long contentLength() throws IOException {
        return multipartBody.contentLength();
    }

    @Override
    public MediaType contentType() {
        return multipartBody.contentType();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
        mCountingSink = new CountingSink(sink);
        BufferedSink bufferedSink = Okio.buffer(mCountingSink);
        multipartBody.writeTo(bufferedSink);
        bufferedSink.flush();
    }

    public interface ProgressListener {
        void transferred(String key, int num);
    }

    protected final class CountingSink extends ForwardingSink {
        private long bytesWritten = 0;

        public CountingSink(Sink delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(Buffer source, long byteCount) throws IOException {
            bytesWritten += byteCount;
            listener.transferred(key, (int) (100F * bytesWritten / contentLength()));
            super.write(source, byteCount);
            delegate().flush(); // I have added this line to manually flush the sink
        }
    }

}
```

The problem here is, the data is written to the sink immediately without actually sending the buffered bytes to the server. Meaning my progress reaches the end long before the actual upload.
***Note:*** [Some say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26376724/370073) that the sink needs to be flushed on every iteration for bytes to be actually uploaded but it's not working for me.

Comment: Checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962595/tracking-progress-of-multipart-file-upload-using-okhttp#) which seems to be similar to yours

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for someone with same problem, I had adapted a helper class (ProgressOutputStream) from this lib: https://github.com/lizhangqu/CoreProgress and my working code is as follow: (working for uploading files and for uploading json too)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okio.BufferedSink;
import okio.Okio;

public class UploadProgressRequestBody extends RequestBody {
    private final RequestBody requestBody;
    private final ProgressListener progressListener;

    public UploadProgressRequestBody(RequestBody requestBody) {
        this.requestBody = requestBody;
        this.progressListener = getDefaultProgressListener();
    }

    @Override public MediaType contentType() {
        return requestBody.contentType();
    }

    @Override public long contentLength() {
        try {
            return requestBody.contentLength();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
        if (progressListener == null) {
            requestBody.writeTo(sink);
            return;
        }
        ProgressOutputStream progressOutputStream = new ProgressOutputStream(sink.outputStream(), progressListener, contentLength());
        BufferedSink progressSink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(progressOutputStream));
        requestBody.writeTo(progressSink);
        progressSink.flush();
    }

    interface ProgressListener {
        void update(long bytesWritten, long contentLength);
    }

    private ProgressListener getDefaultProgressListener(){
        ProgressListener progressListener = new UploadProgressRequestBody.ProgressListener() {
            @Override public void update(long bytesRead, long contentLength) {
                System.out.println("bytesRead: "+bytesRead);
                System.out.println("contentLength: "+contentLength);
                System.out.format("%d%% done\n", (100 * bytesRead) / contentLength);
            }
        };

        return progressListener;
    }

}
```

===========

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class ProgressOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private final OutputStream stream;
    private final UploadProgressRequestBody.ProgressListener listener;

    private long total;
    private long totalWritten;

    ProgressOutputStream(OutputStream stream, UploadProgressRequestBody.ProgressListener listener, long total) {
        this.stream = stream;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.total = total;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        this.stream.write(b, off, len);
        if (this.total < 0) {
            this.listener.update(-1, -1);
            return;
        }
        if (len < b.length) {
            this.totalWritten += len;
        } else {
            this.totalWritten += b.length;
        }
        this.listener.update(this.totalWritten, this.total);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        this.stream.write(b);
        if (this.total < 0) {
            this.listener.update(-1, -1);
            return;
        }
        this.totalWritten++;
        this.listener.update(this.totalWritten, this.total);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (this.stream != null) {
            this.stream.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        if (this.stream != null) {
            this.stream.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

==========

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();

            if (originalRequest.body() == null) {
                return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
            }

            Request progressRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .method(originalRequest.method(),
                            new UploadProgressRequestBody(originalRequest.body()))
                    .build();

            return chain.proceed(progressRequest);
        }
    }).build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. The progressListener always returns 100%. bytesRead and contentLength are always same.

Comment: @Deepakkaku I am using exactly the same code to communicate between android and a php server and it is working fine. On the server I add in the request response the headers 'Content-Encoding: gzip' and "Content-Length:". strlen($replyBody)

Answer (score 1):

After a tiresome day of digging, I found this genius's solution to set the buffer size at the network interface level. My problem was that the progress was jumping right away (in a blink) to more than its half. It turned out that my input stream was being read and the buffer (output stream) was being written to until the system decided it's enough, consumed it, then proceeded.. This made it impossible to track the upload progress accurately. Have a look:
[Fix for upload progress monitoring in Android.](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/00a26683ea68856ceb50e26c7d8a47d0)

Try the class and set its sendBufferSize to something small yet reasonable or whatever proves appropriate.

```
int sendBufferSize = 128 * 1028;
new OkHttpClient.Builder().socketFactory(new RestrictedSocketFactory(sendBufferSize));
```

A side note for the problem of progress jumping to 100: I've come across many answers suggesting that it's due to OkHttp logging. Try to turn it off and see if that helps.