# Android Upload file Percentage ProgressBar with OKHTTP3

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Does anyone know how i can add a **progress bar that tells me how much of the file has been uploaded**. This is what i have managed to do in the code below, i have managed to pick a file from my phone and have also managed to send it, but the problem is if i am uploading a huge file i keep waiting not knowing when it will finish and that is why i need a progress bar that shows me how much has been transferred to the server. This is the code that i have i have tried different implementations but to no avail.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button fileUploadBtn;
protected static String IPADDRESS = "http://10.42.0.1/hugefile/save_file.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fileUploadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFileUpload);
    pickFile();

}

private void pickFile() {

    fileUploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MaterialFilePicker()
                    .withActivity(MainActivity.this)
                    .withRequestCode(10).start();
        }
    });
}

ProgressDialog progress;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progress.setTitle("Uploading File(s)");
    progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progress.show();
    if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                File f = new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH));

                String content_type = getMimeType(f.getPath());
                String file_path = f.getAbsolutePath();

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type), f);
                RequestBody request_body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("type", content_type)
                        .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file", file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), file_body).build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(IPADDRESS)
                        .post(request_body)
                        .build();
                try {

                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    Log.d("Server response", response.body().string());
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw new IOException("Error : " + response);
                    }
                    progress.dismiss();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }
}

private String getMimeType(String path) {
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think your whole solution need some corrections. Pausing user with some dialog is bad practice, also your upload progress can be lost if config changes. And new Thread I really too crude nowadays. So first of all I advise you to move code of upload process​ in Service or IntentService. You can show progress and status in notification and then alert user with dialog or snackbar, etc. Secondly there is no straight way to monitor progress of upload. Generally best way is implementing custom RequestBody which will notify bytes uploaded via listener. Please reffer to [Tracking progress of multipart file upload using OKHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962595/tracking-progress-of-multipart-file-upload-using-okhttp) 
Then you can use broadcasts or event bus to publish progress.

Answer (score 1):

i managed to solve it with a bit of some improvements and here is the link to the solution for anyone who encounters the same problem 
https://github.com/MakuSimz/Android-Multipart-Upload-with-Progress