# Android HttpPost and HttpClient Substitute

Tags: http-post, httpclient, deprecated, multipartentity, httpentity

Just a quick question.
Until now I have been using HttpClient and HttpPost to post a file and some parameters to a php script on my server.
However they have been deprecated.
I was wondering what i could use to substitute it.
I found some answers on other posts but unfortunately i didn't manage to integrate any of them with the HttpMime Library that i am using for a MultiPartEntity post.

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();        // Deprecated
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(inData[0].URL);         // Deprecated

            // Request To Entity
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            // Add Parameters
        for(Request r : inData[0].Params)
            entity.addPart(r.Key, new StringBody(r.Body));
            // Add File
        entity.addPart("img", new FileBody(inData[0].FileToUpload));

        httpost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse responsePOST = httpclient.execute(httpost);    // Deprecated
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();            // Deprecated
        if (resEntity != null)
            inData[0].RequestResult.add(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        else
            throw new Exception("");
        return inData[0];

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        inData[0].RequestResult.add("ERROR");
    }
    return inData[0];
```

Would anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At my job we also used the apache libraries but we have replaced them with okHTTP.

More information about okHTTP can be found here: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Information about uploading multipart files can be found here:

[Uploading a large file in multipart using OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279563/uploading-a-large-file-in-multipart-using-okhttp)