# Android okHttp addFormDataPart dynamically for Multiple Image

Tags: java, android, file-upload, okhttp, multipart

I had given answer **[Uploading a large file in multipart using OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34127008/1318946)** but i am stuck with multiple image uploading.

I want to upload dynamically **1 to 10** image at a time.

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                    .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart(KEY_PHOTO_CAPTION, photoCaption)
                    .addFormDataPart(KEY_FILE, "profile.png", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile))
                    .build();
```

I have `ArrayList` of **PhotoCaption** class which has **`captionPhoto`** and **`urlPhoto`** so how can i **addFormDataPart()**

I am thinking to make loop and call this function that many times of **ArrayList** size.

Is there any solution to **addFormDataPart()** use dynamically?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**This answer is for OkHttp2**

For OkHttp3 You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930167/upload-dynamic-number-of-files-with-okhttp3).

For multiple image you just need to run the loop as per your requirement, remaining part related to request will be same as you do.

```
  //  final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");
final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE=MediaType.parse(AppConstant.arrImages.get(i).getMediaType());

//If you can have multiple file types, set it in ArrayList
                    MultipartBuilder buildernew = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                            .addFormDataPart("title", title)

                    for (int i = 0; i < AppConstants.arrImages.size(); i++) {
                        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                                TEMP_FILE_NAME + i + ".png");
                        if (f.exists()) {
                            buildernew.addFormDataPart(TEMP_FILE_NAME + i, TEMP_FILE_NAME + i + FILE_EXTENSION, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, f));
                        }
                    }
                    RequestBody requestBody = buildernew.build();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(Url.URL + Url.INSERT_NEWS)
                            .post(requestBody)
                            .build();

                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    return response.body().string();
```

Dont forget to **delete** temp. files that you uploaded *if it is of no use.*

Comment: I am selecting dynamically like **2 png**, **3 gif** and **5 jpeg** then?

Comment: **Update May 2016** : MultipartBuilder is now replaced by MultipartBody.Builder ;-)

Answer (score 18):

Here I have created Function to Upload Multiple Images.

```
/**
 * Here I am uploading MultipleImages from List of photoCaption
 * Sending photoCaption with URL and Caption of Photo...
 *
 * @param albumId
 * @param photoCaptions
 * @return
 */
public static JSONObject uploadAlbumImage(String albumId, ArrayList<PhotoCaption> photoCaptions) {

    try {

        MultipartBuilder multipartBuilder = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM);

        int length = photoCaptions.size();
        int noOfImageToSend = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            /**
             * Getting Photo Caption and URL
             */
            PhotoCaption photoCaptionObj = photoCaptions.get(i);
            String photoUrl = photoCaptionObj.getPhotoUrl();
            String photoCaption = photoCaptionObj.getPhotoCaption();

            File sourceFile = new File(photoUrl);

            if(sourceFile.exists()) {
                /** Changing Media Type whether JPEG or PNG **/
                final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse(FileUtils.getExtension(photoUrl).endsWith("png") ? "image/png" : "image/jpeg");

                /** Adding in MultipartBuilder **/
                multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart(KEY_IMAGE_CAPTION + i, photoCaption);
                multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart(KEY_IMAGE_NAME + i, sourceFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, sourceFile));

                /** Counting No Of Images **/
                noOfImageToSend++;
            }
        }

        RequestBody requestBody = multipartBuilder
                .addFormDataPart(KEY_ALBUM_ID, albumId)
                .addFormDataPart(KEY_IMAGE_COUNT, String.valueOf(noOfImageToSend))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL_ALBUM_UPLOAD_IMAGE)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        /** Your Response **/
        String responseStr = response.body().string();

        Log.i(TAG, "responseStr : "+ responseStr);

        return new JSONObject(responseStr);

    } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Other Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Check Edited Answer for [**okhttp3**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34127008/1318946)