# How to add list of Object (i.e UserData) type to MultipartBody in OkHttpClient

Tags: android, json, multipartform-data, okhttp

I have an ArrayList of Object that I need to put into my MultipartBody.Builder.I have tried using different methods of .addFormDataPart but not working. This is how I'm putting it into the request. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

My JSON on the server is formatted like this

```
 {
      "formData": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "value": {
            any-object(string,file,long....etc)
          }
        }
      ],
      "tripId": "string"
    }
```

This is how I am doing it

```
private RequestBody getMultipartData(Object postData) {
        MultipartBody.Builder formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder();
        formBody.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

        ArrayList<UserData> arrayList = null;
        if (postData instanceof OnboardPresenterImpl.TripRequest) {
            OnboardPresenterImpl.TripRequest tripRequest = ((OnboardPresenterImpl.TripRequest) postData);
            formBody.addFormDataPart("tripId", tripRequest.getTripId());
            arrayList = tripRequest.getFormData();

        } 

        if (arrayList != null && arrayList.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

                UserData userData = arrayList.get(i);

                String value = userData.getValue().toLowerCase();

                if (value.contains("/") && (value.contains(".png") ||
                        value.contains(".jpeg") || value.contains(".jpg"))) {

                    MediaType type = Util.getMediaType(value);

                    File sourceFile = new File(value);

                    if (sourceFile.exists()) {

                        formBody.addFormDataPart(userData.getName(),
                                sourceFile.getName(),RequestBody.create(type, sourceFile));

                    }
                } else {
                    formBody.addFormDataPart(userData.getName(), value);
                }
            }
        }

       return formBody.build();
    }
```

Comment: You can send object type using JSON as String.

Comment: can you please show some example

Comment: May be it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/19026256/1318946

Comment: this is not helpful at all because my format of sending data is different

Comment: @Rahul IN the backend there is a curl request

Comment: @Jatin I am not able to create above format.please help

Comment: @dharman above-mentioned use case is completely different from the link you added. So please undelete this post.

Comment: You accepted the answer so I assumed it was the same. If it's not the same then why did you accept the answer? I reopened it but I am not going to undelete the answer below because it's exactly the same. Frankly, I don't understand why you say it's not the same.