# Multiple image uploading using multipart retrofit or volley

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit2, multipartform-data

Hi Can any one Please help me out in uploading multiple images selected from gallery,
parameter is 'images' as array list 
I have tried with this but no response can any one help me out..

This is my request body :

```
  MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
    MultipartBody.Builder mRequestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
    if (Imagepaths.size() > 0) {
        for(String path:Imagepaths) {
            File file = new File(path);
            mediaType = path.endsWith("png") ?
                    MediaType.parse("image/png") : MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
            RequestBody imageBody = RequestBody.create(mediaType, file);
            mRequestBody.addFormDataPart("images", file.getName(), imageBody);
        }
    }

    RequestBody rb = mRequestBody.build();
```

This is the retrofit call :

```
 @Multipart
@POST("upload_images/")
Call<ResponseBody> retrofitImageUpload(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                                       @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
                                       @Part("images") RequestBody req);
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: https://medium.com/@adinugroho/upload-image-from-android-app-using-retrofit-2-ae6f922b184c

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395873/android-okhttp-addformdatapart-dynamically-for-multiple-image/34411666#34411666)

Comment: try using
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866676/retrofit-uploading-multiple-images-to-a-single-key

Comment: ImagePaths is the uri array list i get from selected image eg: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_20180928-19451.jpg

Comment: @ahuja007 Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-using-retrofit-2-in-android?noredirect=1#comment111031344_62783444