# Can't access POST parameter in okhttp3 Android

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using `okhttp3` for upload image on server and i success in Upload image but i can not POST parameter with `MultipartBody`

**my code is here..**

```
File sourceFile = new File(sourceImageFile);

            Log.logInfo("File...::::" + sourceFile + " : " + sourceFile.exists());

            final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");


            OkHttpClient client = App.getInstance().getOkHttpClient();

            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken)
                    .addFormDataPart(KEY_FILE, "profile.png", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile))
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL_IMAGE_UPLOAD)
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

           Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I want to add "key" and "value" by POST Method in above code So how can i do.

Answer (score 3):

As I learned before, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/34127008/6554840

In that passed **`member_id`** with its value.

So you are passing values with `KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN` is must be work.

```
.addFormDataPart(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken)
```

will work as post parameter.

I hope it will work.

**Note:** Must be your Web side is working.

Comment: but i can't get this post data in PHP server side in middle were interceoter.

Comment: I dont know more about that. If you get the solution then please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Use this you have to create `HashMap<String, String>` this way and `add` it to `Builder`.

These are the Imports.

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
```

Code:

```
// HashMap with Params
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put( "Param1", "A" );
params.put( "Param2", "B" );

// Initialize Builder (not RequestBody)
FormBody.Builder builder = new FormBody.Builder();

// Add Params to Builder
for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet() ) {
    builder.add( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
}

// Create RequestBody
RequestBody formBody = builder.build();

// Create Request (same)
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url( "url" )
        .post( formBody )
        .build();
```